# Bash script output not going to stdout

Tags: linux, bash, stdout

I have a build process, kicked off by `Make`, that executes a lot of child scripts.

A couple of these child scripts require `root privileges`, so instead of running everything as `root`, or everything as `sudo`, I'm trying to only execute the scripts that need to be as `root`, as `root`.

I'm accomplishing this like so:

```
execute_as_user() {

    su "$1" -s /bin/bash -c "$2;exit \$?"

}
```

Arg $1 is the user to run the script as, arg $2 is the script.

Arg $1 is either `root` (gotten with: `$(whoami)` since everything is under sudo), or the current user's account (gotten with: `$(logname)`)

The entire build is kicked off as:

```
sudo make all
```

Sample from the Makefile:

```
LOG="runtime.log"
ROTATE_LOG:=$(shell bash ./scripts/utils/rotate_log.sh)

system:
    /bin/bash -c "time ./scripts/system.sh 2>&1 | tee ${LOG}"
```

My problem is... none of the child scripts are printing output to `stdout`. I believe it to be some sort of issue with an almost recursive call of `su root`... but I'm unsure. From my understanding, these scripts should already be outputting to `stdout`, so perhaps I'm mistaken where the output is going?

To be clear, I'm seeing no output in either the logfile nor displaying to the terminal (stdout).

`Updating for clarity:`

Previously, I just ran all the scripts either with `sudo` or just as the logged in user... which with my makefile above, would print to the terminal (`stdout`) and logfile. Adding the `execute_as_user()` function is where the issue cropped up. The scripts execute and build the project... just no display "that it's working" and no logs.

`UPDATE`

Here is some snippets:

system.sh snippet:

```
execute_script() {
    echo "Executing as user $3: $2"
    RETURN=$(execute_as_user $3 ${SYSTEM_SCRIPTS}/$2)
    if [ ${RETURN} -ne ${OK} ]
    then
        error $1 $2 ${RETURN}
    fi
}

build_package() {
    local RETURN=0
    case "$1" in
        system)
            declare -a scripts=(\
                "rootfs.sh" \
                "base_files.sh" \
                "busybox.sh" \
                "iana-etc.sh" \
                "kernel.sh" \
                "firmware.sh" \
                "bootscripts.sh" \
                "network.sh" \
                "dropbear.sh" \
                "wireless_tools.sh" \
                "e2fsprogs.sh" \
                "shared_libs.sh"
            )

            for SCRIPT_NAME in "${scripts[@]}"; do
                execute_script $1 ${SCRIPT_NAME} $(logname)
                echo ""
                echo -n "${SCRIPT_NAME}"
                show_status ${OK}
                echo ""
            done

            # finalize base system
            echo ""
            echo "Finalizing base system"
            execute_script $1 "finalize.sh" $(whoami)
            echo ""
            echo -n "finalize.sh"
            show_status ${OK}
            echo ""

            # package into tarball
            echo ""
            echo "Packing base system"
            execute_script $1 "archive.sh" $(whoami)
            echo ""
            echo -n "archive.sh"
            show_status ${OK}
            echo ""

            echo ""
            echo -n "Build System: "
            show_status ${OK}
            ;;
        *)
            echo "$1 is not supported!"
            exit 1
    esac
}
```

sample child script executed by system.sh

```
cd ${CLFS_SOURCES}/
tar -xvjf ${PKG_NAME}-${PKG_VERSION}.tar.bz2

cd ${CLFS_SOURCES}/${PKG_NAME}-${PKG_VERSION}/

make distclean
RESPONSE=$?
if [ ${RESPONSE} -ne 0 ]
then
    pkg_error ${RESPONSE}
    exit ${RESPONSE}
fi

ARCH="${CLFS_ARCH}" make defconfig
RESPONSE=$?
if [ ${RESPONSE} -ne 0 ]
then
    pkg_error ${RESPONSE}
    exit ${RESPONSE}
fi

# fixup some bugs with musl-libc
sed -i 's/\(CONFIG_\)\(.*\)\(INETD\)\(.*\)=y/# \1\2\3\4 is not set/g' .config
sed -i 's/\(CONFIG_IFPLUGD\)=y/# \1 is not set/' .config

etc...
```

Here's the entire system.sh script:

https://github.com/SnakeDoc/LiLi/blob/master/scripts/system.sh

(i know the project is messy... it's a learn-as-you-go style project)

Comment: BTW, you don't need the `exit` statement. The exit status of a shell is always the exit status of the last command that it executed.

Comment: `su` doesn't do its own redirection. So if you're not redirecting the output, it should go to the original stdout, which goes to the pipe.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the tip. I had assumed that since it was wrapped in a function, that i would need to explicitly set the exit code otherwise it may get messed with somehow.

Comment: That exit command is just exiting from the `bash -c` shell, it doesn't exit the function.

Comment: the problem must be somewhere in `system.sh`. Can you post a small version of it that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @Barmar I seem to get stderr and some echos now that I'm running the script again... so only stdout is going someplace I'm not expecting. I'll update my OP with a snippet of system.sh and a sample child script system.sh will execute.

Comment: Also recall that running `/bin/bash -c "time ./scripts/system.sh 2>&1 | tee ${LOG}"` runs `time ./scripts/system.sh` as `root`, but the redirection **and** `tee` runs as the normal user.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin right, which means logs get created as the root user... which is acceptable.

Comment: @Barmar et al.. updated with snippets and a link to the full script.

Comment: You're running `execute_as_user` inside `RETURN=$(...)`. So all the output is put in the variable.

Comment: @SnakeDoc just the opposite. If you are running something with sudo and trying to write to files owned by root with redirection, that will likely fail. Example `sudo echo "some text" >> /var/log/syslog` (or any file with only root write permissions). The `echo` command runs as `root` but the redirection `>>` runs as `user` so the write fails. If you have similar redirection in your code, that may be one source, if not a primary source, of the output problem.

Comment: @Barmar your last comment -- `execute_as_user` is nested inside `execute_script`. So each child script of `system.sh` will be run from `execute_script` which in turn calls `execute_as_user` among other things.

Comment: @Barmar RE: `execute_as_user` inside `RETURN$(...)`... I think you may be right. I need to get the return code from the child script for some error checking purposes... is there a way I can avoid stuffing my output into `RETURN` while still capturing the child script's exit code?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin that could explain nothing in the logs... but wouldn't explain no output to stdout?

Comment: Use `$?` just like you do elsewhere in the script.

Comment: BTW, you can simplify all of those to `if ! command; then ...; fi`

Comment: @Barmar switching to `$?` did the trick. Thanks a lot for your help and tips, I still have a lot to learn with bash. Please do a quick answer so I can give you some points :)

Comment: @SnakeDoc The lack of output to stdout isn't one I can explain in general. Recall with pipes, each command in a pipeline is executed in its own subshell. (Section 3.2.2 of Bash Ref. Manual) Redirection from subshells is tricky and something I have to look up for each situation (far too old to remember it all). I suspect that subshell redirection is part of the problem, but you will have to take it call by call, especially when part of the output comes from a subshell owned by root and the next owned by a regular user.

Answer (score 0):

> Previously, I just ran all the scripts either with sudo or just as the
>   logged in user... which with my makefile above, would print to the
>   terminal (stdout) and logfile. Adding the execute_as_user() function
>   is where the issue cropped up. The scripts execute and build the
>   project... just no display "that it's working" and no logs.

Just a guess, but you're probably not calling your function or not calling it properly:

```
execute_as_user() {

    su "$1" -s /bin/bash -c "$2;exit \$?"

}

execute_as_user "$@"
```

I also noticed that you're not passing any argument to the script at all. Is this meant?

```
./scripts/system.sh ???
```

Comment: all functions/scripts run... the build will complete and everything is fine. Just no stdout (stderr seems to be ok).

Comment: @SnakeDOc Does it make a difference if you don't add the `time` command?